# How to clear Exchange mail queues using PowerShell for a specific user

Tags: exchange, powershell

Recently, my organization were victim of a spam attack. Sadly, some users provided their email and password. The attacker set up a long queue of emails to be sent (from the victims account).

We had to delete all the message manually (from the queue viewer). It was very painful (more than 100 thousands emails...).

Is it possible to clear the email queue of a specific user with the PowerShell ? (using the Active Directory module)

Found this [old post](https://serverfault.com/questions/1745/how-to-clear-exchange-mail-queues-using-powershell), but it look outdated and it delete **all** the queue...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just have to add a `Where-Object` (abbreviated to `?`) after `Get-Message` to select the messages you want to remove.

```
Get-ExchangeServer |
    ?{$_.IsHubTransportServer -eq $true} |
    Get-Queue |
    get-message |
    ? {$_.sender -eq 'Vinc@somedomain.uhoh'} |
    Remove-Message -withNDR $false
```

Comment: Is it possible to add the parameter -server + -credential (im running the command in remote)?

Comment: You should probably connect using a separate command first. Then any future Exchange commands will be issued against that Exchange org.

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you a lot ! I am now ready for the next spam attack ! Watch out ! :)